# Can't find a codec for class org.apache.logging.log4j.mongodb4.MongoDb4DocumentObject

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, log4j2

ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender Mongo4 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Unable to write to database in appender: Can't find a codec for class org.apache.logging.log4j.mongodb4.MongoDb4DocumentObject。

don't occur exception，return normal。

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade the log4j2 version to 2.17.2. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues/1439) for more information.